# Can I write "at a pretty high outflow"?

Tags: word-usage

On [an other Stack Exchange forum, I asked a question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/lots-of-bubbles-getting-out-of-a-freshly-cut-lotus-stem) and I wrote this sentence :

> I started to worry when I realized that it had been minutes and
>   minutes (I would say at least 10) since the bubbles were getting out
>   of it **at a pretty high outflow** (bubbles were constantly getting out).

Is it right ? I am specifically wondering it about the end of the sentence that I putted in bold (can we say "**at a pretty high** outflow" ?). By the way, does the word "outflow" fits well to the context here ?

Comment: The sentence can be written in a better way -- *I started worrying when I realized that the bubbles were coming out pretty much fast for more than 10 minutes.*

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you for this suggestion. When you say better, do you mean that the way I told it was incorrect ? Or does your suggestion just makes it sounding better ?

Comment: I mean the latter one. Also, the sentence should look in flow, natural.

Comment: @MaulikV You need to remove 'much' from your suggestion.  _I started worrying when I realized that the bubbles were coming out pretty fast for more than 10 minutes_. 'Pretty' describes the speed all by itself.

Comment: @mcalex yeah, but I can write that way to emphasize the 'already emphasized' thing! ;) http://www.mag4all.com/this-velociraptor-look-alike-robot-runs-much-faster-humans/

Comment: Your emphasis comes at a cost of correctness.  'Pretty much fast' is wrong, grammatically.  If you want to empahsize perhaps 'incredibly fast' or 'amazingly fast' might work better

Answer (score 1):

"At a pretty high outflow" is an awkward construction for this sentence. "High outflow" sounds like dry technical jargon, which would seem inappropriate for the tone of the sentence. Without some more context for this sentence, I couldn't suggest more that trying to describe the bubbling using an adverb like quickly, steadily, strongly, furiously, etc.